# How to choose the calendar to which you are adding an event

Tags: google-calendar

I have two calendars in my google account. One is for personal events and the other is for workplace events. Whenever I add an event, it adds it to my personal calendar by default. On the screen where I edit event details, I do not see a place where I can specify that the event be added to the workplace calendar. Is there a place where I can make this choice?

Also, is there a way to move an event from one calendar in your account to another without first copying it and then deleting the event from the old calendar.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq). Questions about Web apps are considered off topic on Super User. Questions within this scope are better fit on our Q&A website http://webapps.stackexchange.com which is currently in open beta. Your contribution will help it stay alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of my calendar entry methods (click on the day, or click the "New Event" button) have a "Calendar: " and then a drop-down menu listing all of the calendars. Where are you entering the information?

Also, when editing an existing event, again, there is a drop-down menu with list of calendars. Are both of your calendars default Google calendars, or is one hosted elsewhere and Google subscribes to it?

Comment: Same for me as well.

Comment: Somehow I completely missed it. 

Why is this question closed by the way? There is a category for Google Calendar and it is a question related to its usage, and hence related to software usage!